# How to best use a scipy sparse matrix for distributing training with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scipy, tf.keras, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm using Vertex AI on GCP to perform distributed training in Keras, but my input feature vectors are very large and sparse, and a scipy sparse matrix is the only reasonable way to process them. I'm trying to convert it to a DistributedDataset, and my code is as follows (x_train is a scipy_sparse csr_matrix, y_train is a numpy array, and x_val and y_val are the validation data):

```
    x = tf.SparseTensor(indices=np.vstack([*x_train.nonzero()]).T, 
                        values=x_train.data[x_train.data != 0],
                        dense_shape=x_train.shape)
    y = tf.constant(y_train)

    xv = tf.SparseTensor(indices=np.vstack([*x_val.nonzero()]).T, 
                        values=x_val.data[x_val.data != 0],
                        dense_shape=x_val.shape)
    yv = tf.constant(y_val)
    ds = self.strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(
              tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(NNModel.BATCH_SIZE))
    vds = self.strategy.experimental_distribute_dataset(
            tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xv, yv)).batch(NNModel.BATCH_SIZE))

    history = self.model.fit(
        x=ds,
        batch_size=NNModel.BATCH_SIZE, epochs=NNModel.NUM_EPOCHS,
        validation_data=vds,
        steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0]/NNModel.BATCH_SIZE,
        validation_steps=x_val.shape[0]/NNModel.BATCH_SIZE,
        verbose=2)
```

The result, in distributed training, is some very odd and suspicious performance on metrics - each epoch looks something like this:

> 1853/1853 - 83s - loss: 2.0610 - accuracy: 0.9700 - true_positives: 263335.0000 - false_positives: 8839.0000 - false_negatives: 7199.0000 - true_negatives: 254447.0000 - auc: 0.9893 - val_loss: 5.0740 - val_accuracy: 0.4928 - val_true_positives: 0.0000e+00 - val_false_positives: 0.0000e+00 - val_false_negatives: 67682.0000 - val_true_negatives: 65773.0000 - val_auc: 0.6736 - 83s/epoch - 45ms/step

Using (x_train, y_train) for training on a single instance seems to work fine, but is slow. Is something wrong with my conversion to SparseTensor, or with the distributed conversion? How can I slice the training data for better performance?

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a [support plan](https://cloud.google.com/support/) please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.